# Finding"NoData" area/percentage using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: raster, arcmap, polygon, landsat-8, nodata

I have a RGB raster that has been processed to remove cloud/shadow coverage and then put in a mosaic with other RGB rasters to fill in the missing gaps.  Unfortunately all the gaps have not been covered, so I have "NoData" areas.

I need to find either the area of those gaps or the percentage based on the entire area of those gaps.

I was recommended to convert my raster to a polygon, but I continue to get a general error message, `One of more dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control.`

I thought this error had to do with having multiple values for one cell (RGB), so I converted it to a single band grey scale using the following method: [Convert raster to polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172279/convert-raster-to-polygon).  However, I still get the same error.

How might I go about this process?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the IsNull() spatial analyst tool. This creates a binary raster 1 for where it is NODATA and 0 for all other values. As the output is an integer grid you can create an attribute table and simply count how many 1 cells you have and that's your area.

This could very easily be wrapped up in ModelBuilder for mass automation.

Comment: I ran the SetNull() tool and was given an output file, with values ranging from -129 to 1.  However, there is no map when I zoom to the layer.

Comment: The `SetNull()` tool returns a binary raster which contain only `1` or `0`. Why you are ending up with -129 I can't really comment on until we see your data?

Comment: I ended up doing it another way where I had a shapefile that contained all the clouds/shadows, so I just used that.